# PHP AJAX email file attachment

Tags: php, ajax, email

I am not able to attach file in PHP email. The following works fine when the file is not attached.

On attaching file, error is thrown `Error! Please try again later.'`

Error log `PHP Warning:  mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header in /home/..../mail.php on line 177`

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['X-Requested-With']) && !isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) {
    die();
}

$tmp = date('r');
$message = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>";
$message .= "<p><strong></strong>{$val['txtName']}</p>";
$message .= "<p><strong></strong>{$val['txtEmail']}</p>";
$message .= "<p><strong> </strong>{$val['txtSubject']}</p>";
$message .= "<p><strong></strong>{$val['txtPhone']}</p>";
$message .= "<p><strong></strong>{$val['txtText']}</p><br>";
$message .= "</body></html>";

        if (isset($_FILES)) {    

        $filename = $_FILES["txtFile"]["name"];
        $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

        $headers = "From: " . $val['txtName'] . " <" . $val['txtEmail'] . ">\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $val['txtName'] . " <" . $val['txtEmail'] . ">\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $uid . "\"\r\n";
        $headers .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
        $headers .= "--" . $uid . "\r\n";

        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n";
        $headers .= $message . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "--" . $uid . "\r\n";

        $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["txtFile"]["tmp_name"])));
        $headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"" . $filename . "\"\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\"\r\n";
        $headers .= $content . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "--" . $uid . "--";

    } else {

        $headers = "From: {$val['txtName']} <" . $val['txtEmail'] . ">\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: {$val['txtName']} <" . $val['txtEmail'] . ">\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    }

    if (mail('info@mail.com', $val['txtSubject'], $message, $headers)) {
        die(json_encode(array(
            'error' => '0',
            'title' => 'Success! Your message has been sent.'
        )));
    } else {
    die(json_encode(array(
        'error' => '1',
        'title' => 'Error! Please try again later.'
    )));
}
```

Tried another header set (but same problem):

```
$file = fopen($_FILES["txtFile"]["tmp_name"], "r");
if ($file == false) {

    die(json_encode(array(
        'code' => 'error',
        'title' => 'Error! Could not read the file.'
    )));

}

$size = $_FILES["txtFile"]["size"];
$content = fread($file, $size);


$encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));


$num = md5(time());


$header = "From: " . $val['txtName'] . " <" . $val['txtEmail'] . ">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: " . $val['txtName'] . " <" . $val['txtEmail'] . ">\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; ";
$header .= "boundary=$num\r\n";
$header .= "--$num\r\n";


$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:8bit\r\n\n";
$header .= "$message\r\n";
$header .= "--$num\r\n";



  $header .= "Content-Type:  multipart/mixed; ";
  $header .= "name=\"$filename\"\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding:base64\r\n";
  $header .= "Content-Disposition:attachment; ";
  $header .= "filename=\"$filename\"\r\n\n";
  $header .= "$encoded_content\r\n";
  $header .= "--$num--";
```

Please let me know where I am making mistake.

Comment: Error log: `mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header in /home/...../mail.php on line 109`

Answer (score 0):

The best way todo this, is to not create the mail header by yourself. It's not that easy to have all rules aligned when doing so.

I recommend to use any library (for example: phpMailer), it will help you a lot and your code become much cleaner, and more maintainable.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this works fine when tested with non-ajax.

Comment: Creating some problem with ajax call